# SQL - Creating a joined temp table

Tags: sql, inner-join, temp-tables

I am looking to join two tables into a temp table, then use the temp table in a select query. This is the select statement for the temp table I want to create:

```
select program, event
from OMEGA.HP
inner join POM.GT
on program = substring(name,7,4)
where LENGTH(name)= 25
```

What is the easiest way to create a temp table for the above?

Answer (score 7):

You can create a temp table (and you might want to), but if you don't know already, I want to point out you can create a virtual temp table in a query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  select program, event
  from OMEGA.HP
  inner join POM.GT on program = substring(name,7,4)
  where LENGTH(name)= 25
) AS Virtual_table
```

you could even join to another of these tables like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  select program, event
  from OMEGA.HP
  inner join POM.GT on program = substring(name,7,4)
  where LENGTH(name)= 25
) AS v_table74
join (
  select program, event
  from OMEGA.HP
  inner join POM.GT on program = substring(name,2,5)
  where LENGTH(name)= 25
) as v_table25 on v_table74.program = v_table25.program
```

Comment: whats the difference between a virtual temp table and a CTE?

Comment: @Manakin -- a CTE is managed by the server -- temp tables are managed by the user.

Comment: which of that is recomendable

Comment: @D4ITON -- it depends a lot on your use case.  In some cases one will work better than the other.

Answer (score 2):

```
select program, event
into #temp    --------------------------------check here
from OMEGA.HP
inner join POM.GT
on program = substring(name,7,4)
where LENGTH(name)= 25
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
with temptablename(program, event) as (
  select program, event
  from OMEGA.HP
  inner join POM.GT
    on program = substring(name,7,4)
  where LENGTH(name)= 25
)
select program, event
from temptablename;
```